# How to remove specific string with numbers in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that has `$23!` or `$9!` in it. I've tried using the following function to remove that part in the string (including `$` and `!` ) but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

```
function remove($t) {
    return preg_replace('$/[0-9]+/!','',$t);
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using `/` at wrong places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using `/` at wrong places and need to escape `$` because it have a [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

**Regex:** `/\$[0-9]+!/`

**Flags to use:**

- `g` for global search i.e all results. ( If anyone wishes to use this in other regex flavors.)

[**Php function**](https://ideone.com/3UDPGd)

```
<?php
function remove($t) 
{ 
    return preg_replace('/\$[0-9]+!/','',$t); 
} 
echo remove("Hello $23! world $2! today");
?>
```

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ7mI9/1)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/dZCvZE)**</kbd>

Comment: You don't need the `g` modifier, `preg_replace` always replaces all the matches.

Comment: I think using \d instead of [0-9] would be better to handle foreign digits as well.

Comment: @Dev.Tareq: I agree with you, but OP didn't mentioned anything about foreign digits. More ever it's not **user input** that OP is trying to match here. If that part is reflected in string after a user input I expect OP to mention it. So for now `[0-9]` is just fine.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks. Added a side note.

Comment: Just to confirm the function to use is:
   [code]function remove($t) {
    return preg_replace('$/\[0-9]+/!','',$t);
    }
[/code]

There are no foreign digits in the string.

Comment: @BusinessLegions: You are again misplacing `/`. [Check function demo](https://ideone.com/3UDPGd).

Comment: @noob Sorry, I was going to edit the regex after pasting the original but it didn't work. In any case your solution works perfect. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need delimiters, second, escape the `$`, third, use `\d+`.
In `PHP`, this will be:

```
function remove($t) {
    return preg_replace('~\$\d+!~','',$t);
}
```